# Retrieve value of checkboxes in mvc 5

Tags: checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of checkboxes for every row to mark attendance of the students. I managed to insert values of the checkboxes in the database. However when i try to edit those values, fetched from the database; for every row checkboxes of similar id's gets checked. Although I'm marking check to checkboxes according to the index values, yet no difference was made.

**User.cs**

```cs
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public List<Models.Days> days { get;set;}
```

**StudentAttendanceVM.cs**

```cs
public Models.User user { get; set; }
public Models.StudentBatch studentbatch { get; set; }
```

**Days.cs**

```cs
public class Days
{
    public string dayid { get; set; }
    public string dayname { get; set; }
    public bool ischecked { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```cs
List<Models.Days> day = new List<Models.Days>();
for (int i = 0; i < TotalCheckBoxes; i++)
{
    day.Add(new Models.Days { dayid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), dayname = getdays[i], ischecked = false });
}

List<Models.StudentAttendance> studentattendance = new List<Models.StudentAttendance>();

foreach (Models.User lst in users)
{
    studentattendance.Add(new Models.StudentAttendance { studentbatch = new Models.StudentBatch  { batchId = id }, user = new Models.User { Id= lst.Id, FirstName = lst.FirstName, LastName = lst.LastName, days = day}});
}

List<string> attendance = contStudent.GetAttendance(id) // here I'm fetching result from database

if (attendance.Count > 0)
{
    string status = "";
    string status1 = "";

    for (int k = 0; k < attendance.Count; k++)
    {
        status = attendance[k].ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < status.Length; i++)
        {
            status1 = status[i].ToString();
            if (status1 == "1")
            {
                studentattendance[k].user.days[i].ischecked = true; // here I'm trying to check the checkbox of particular index, but each item of the same index in studentattendance list gets checked.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generating the variable `day` using

```cs
List<Models.Days> day = new List<Models.Days>();
```

and then assigning that instance (a reference type) to each `User`.

There is only one instance of `day` so any change you make to it is reflected in every `User` model.

You need to make a separate instance of `List<Days>` for each `User`.

```cs
foreach (Models.User lst in users)
{
    // Move the code for initializing the collection of Days here
    List<Models.Days> day = new List<Models.Days>();
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalCheckBoxes; i++)
    {
        day.Add(new Models.Days { dayid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), dayname = getdays[i], ischecked = false });
    }
    studentattendance.Add(new Models.StudentAttendance
    {
        studentbatch = new Models.StudentBatch
        {
            batchId = id
        },
        user = new Models.User
        {
            Id= lst.Id,
            FirstName = lst.FirstName,
            LastName = lst.LastName,
            days = day
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So, i should make separate instance of List<Days> inside loop of user and within that i add values to days as well as in studentattendance list?

Comment: Thank you again Stephen Muecke :)